# Incorrect JSHint warning "variable is defined but never used."

Tags: javascript, jshint

I have the following JS code:

```
var func = function (dimension) {
  var element,
      minSize = "min-" + dimension,
      maxSize = "max-" + dimension;           

  element = jQuery('<div>');
  element.css({
    maxSize: "",
    minSize: ""
  });

};

func();
```

JSHint throws me the following warnings:

> Two unused variables
>
> 3 minSize
>
> 4 maxSize

Why? It is obvious that I'm using them.

Comment: You defined them as `value`, while you use them in `.css` as `key`, so the `variable` ones are never used.

Comment: Excuse my incompetence, but if initially minSize/maxSize are variables, and after that I used them as properties, how do these keys get their assigned values? Is it a bad practice the way I used these variables?

Comment: If you want to use their value as key, `user1465639 `' s answer is what you want.

Comment: Ok, I think I got my mistake, but still can not believe that loose language as JS, allows you to do a lot of crazy things, allows you to do such thing as mentioned above, even interpreted it well, but still this is not correct. Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you havn't use the variable. you can't use literal object with variable as key.
try

```
var func = function (dimension) {
  var element,
      minSize = "min-" + dimension,
      maxSize = "max-" + dimension;           

  element = jQuery('<div>');
  var obj={};
  obj[maxSize]=""
  obj[minSize]=""

  element.css(obj);

};

func();
```

Answer (score 2):

The variables are assigned but not used.

Assignment:

`minSize = "min-" + dimension,
 maxSize = "max-" + dimension;`

Not using `minSize` or `maxSize` but creating two properties with the same names on an anonymous object :

`element.css({
    maxSize: "",
    minSize: ""
  });`